# WebPack 4: devtool eval with minification

Tags: node.js, webpack-4

I'm looking for a WebPack configuration where the size of the bundle is minimal but I can still produce human readable stack traces that refer to the original source files and lines. Column information isn't necessary.

Is it possible to have WebPack 4 minify your code and also use the `devtool: "eval"` mechanism (or some other) so that the stack traces you get during exceptions is nicely formatted with the original source locations?
I tried to combine the `mode: "production"` with the `devtool: "eval"` but they seem to be mutually exclusive, e.g. the presence of one forces the other option to have no effect.

My requirement: the code I deploy in production must produce human readable stack traces. It's a NodeJS 8.x environment inside AWS Lambda.

I'm also trying to keep the size of the bundle the lowest possible because it improves the cold-start time of the Lambda function.

Comment: No, you should be able to use both, mode does not override what was set. eval is not the best, try cheap-module-eval-source-map

Comment: Hmm, I guess what confused me is that with `"eval"` the bundle is 16.6 MB and with `"cheap-module-eval-source-map"` it's 40.9 MB. Somehow the cheap eval is much more "expensive".

Comment: @PlayMa256 could you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Comment: Of course! I'll be posting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cheap-module-eval-source-map` is the smallest type of sourcemap, that you are going to be able to see actual source code (or at least better than just minified code).

You can have a check on the documentation of that [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx). Be aware that you have to sacrifice size to get a good type of sourcemaps. The more precise the sourcemap is, the bigger it gets.